# Send email to customer when Subscription is Cancelled, Expired or Suspended

Tags: woocommerce, subscription

Using latest WooCommerce and WooCommerce Subscriptions and WooCommerce Membership plugins!

By default WooCommerce Subscription plugin sends emails about subscription cancellation, expiration and suspention just to admin, what is really strange. I think that customer should be informed about these actions. Therefore question - has anybody hooked it that such emails are also sent to customers?

Had not find any usefull solution so far for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

to achieve what I want - decided to use this plugin: https://automatewoo.com/.